# How to add a multiline title bar in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, titlebar

I have try to add a two line title bar in UINavigationController

I want to adjust font size automatically set according to string length.My String max size goes to 60. I have try to implemented through following code

```
UILabel *bigLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
bigLabel.text = @"1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123456";
bigLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
bigLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bigLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
bigLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
bigLabel.clipsToBounds = NO;
bigLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
bigLabel.textAlignment = ([self.title length] < 10 ? NSTextAlignmentCenter : NSTextAlignmentLeft);
[bigLabel sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = bigLabel;
```

It didn't work for me can you help me please. I have to made this for iPhone and iPad screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set `setNumberOfLines:` **0** of `UILabel`. See the example below.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[label setText:@"1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123456"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

[image]

Set Left and Right `UIBarButtonItems` - you can add them.

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Left" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(leftPress:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;

UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Right" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(rightPress:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
```

Also decrease the `FontSize` of `Label`. It is **12** in this case.
And it will look like this:

[image]

**For the extended question:**

Just make some changes in previous code -

```
[label setNumberOfLines:2]; //Set it 2 instead of 0

NSString *titleStr = @"3456456676456464554541223434484384233456744444444456785643367";

//Check your string length then set font according to it.
//I have set font size according to your requirement
//which is 0-60.

if([titleStr length]>40 && [titleStr length]<=52){
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13.0]];
}
else if([titleStr length]>52){
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:11.5]];
}

[label setText:titleStr];
```

**Note:** You can't use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:` property of `UILabel`, because it doesn't work for `setNumberOfLines:0` in your case you will have to handle it with `if` condition.

This is method for set `fontSize` Of `UILabel` according to its `width`.

```
[label setNumberOfLines:1];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 1.0;
```

Comment: didn't help me because i have a left and right button in navigation bar

Comment: And you should mentioned your all problems in your question. Because i dont know about your problem I just know what you asked.

Comment: sorry for not describing all. the string very from length 5 to 60 so font size must be flexible and title not more then 2 line. I have already solved solution with fixed font size. I need with flexible font size like adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property

Comment: nice solution. sorry once again it's not helping me the line should not be more than 2 and default size of navigation title is 20 and it should be decrease as per length increase.

Comment: Have you tried last edit part ? ... Lines will not be more than 2.

Comment: I have edit your answer and set according to my requirement. please see my answer

Comment: this works for me for the most part, but unfortunately when clicking back and coming back to the screen with this title, I'm seeing the title text jump from the frame you set to its center position. any thoughts?

Comment: Don't know the exact problem but in this case you can set its frame in `viewWillAppear:` method.

Answer (score 2):

thanks to @TheTiger for such a solution.
I have edited his answer according my requirement. so here is my answer

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
NSString *titleStr1 = @"1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 1234567890 123 4568";
NSString *titleStr  = @"I am a computer engineer. I wa";
NSLog(@"%d", [titleStr length]);

if([titleStr length]>40 && [titleStr length]<=50){
    [label setNumberOfLines:2]; 
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
}
else if([titleStr length]>30 && [titleStr length]<=40){
    [label setNumberOfLines:2]; 
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
}
else if([titleStr length]>50){
    [label setNumberOfLines:2]; 
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10]];
}
else{
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
    [label setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
}
[label setText:titleStr];
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```